# Postgres archive versions

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Trying to import a nightly production backup locally, I ran into this:

> pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header

Now, as to what to do in such a case, [the question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55234984/pg-restore-archiver-unsupported-version-1-13-in-file-header) or [see here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064209/getting-archiver-unsupported-version-1-13-in-file-header-when-running-pg-r).

I'm still left with some **corollary questions** though:

- How can I **check which version of the archive format** a Postgres dump uses, from the command-line?
- How do I **know which Postgres versions support which versions of the archives format?**

I see no obvious link between Postgres versions and Postgres archive formats, meanwhile searching Google or Postgresql.org for "1.14" did not help.

In my case:

- While I can still import dumps produced by Heroku Postgres itself, the nightly export (produced by the Autobus add-on) produces archive versions I can't import locally.
- Upgrading from Postgres 9.6.14 to 9.6.16 did not help. (I take it Autobus is using some Postgres version > 9.6.)

I'd like to know when they changed archive formats by looking up the info for the last X dumps… and from there what my options/requirements are for importing their dumps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_restore -l filename` will tell you the archive version of a PostgreSQL dump.

To know which PostgreSQL version uses which archive format, you'll have to look at the source: [`pg_backup_archiver.h`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/bin/pg_dump/pg_backup_archiver.h), e.g.:

```c
/* Historical version numbers (checked in code) */
#define K_VERS_1_0  MAKE_ARCHIVE_VERSION(1, 0, 0)
#define K_VERS_1_2  MAKE_ARCHIVE_VERSION(1, 2, 0)   /* Allow No ZLIB */
#define K_VERS_1_3  MAKE_ARCHIVE_VERSION(1, 3, 0)   /* BLOBs */
#define K_VERS_1_4  MAKE_ARCHIVE_VERSION(1, 4, 0)   /* Date & name in header */
#define K_VERS_1_5  MAKE_ARCHIVE_VERSION(1, 5, 0)   /* Handle dependencies */
#define K_VERS_1_6  MAKE_ARCHIVE_VERSION(1, 6, 0)   /* Schema field in TOCs */
#define K_VERS_1_7  MAKE_ARCHIVE_VERSION(1, 7, 0)   /* File Offset size in
                                                     * header */
#define K_VERS_1_8  MAKE_ARCHIVE_VERSION(1, 8, 0)   /* change interpretation
                                                     * of ID numbers and
                                                     * dependencies */
#define K_VERS_1_9  MAKE_ARCHIVE_VERSION(1, 9, 0)   /* add default_with_oids
                                                     * tracking */
#define K_VERS_1_10 MAKE_ARCHIVE_VERSION(1, 10, 0)  /* add tablespace */
#define K_VERS_1_11 MAKE_ARCHIVE_VERSION(1, 11, 0)  /* add toc section
                                                     * indicator */
#define K_VERS_1_12 MAKE_ARCHIVE_VERSION(1, 12, 0)  /* add separate BLOB
                                                     * entries */
#define K_VERS_1_13 MAKE_ARCHIVE_VERSION(1, 13, 0)  /* change search_path
                                                     * behavior */
#define K_VERS_1_14 MAKE_ARCHIVE_VERSION(1, 14, 0)  /* add tableam */
```

I recommend that you use a recent version of `pg_restore`: newer versions can read older archive formats.

Note that restoring a dump taken with an old version of `pg_dump` into a newer version of the database is not well supported and can produce surprising results.